# Position child elements of a flexbox with position relative and the top property (right property works but top doesn't)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

```
<div class="b-wrapper d-flex d-flex-center">
     <div class="inner-wrapper">
         <h2 class="b-animate h b-from-top b-delay03">Project 3</h2>
         <p class="b-animate p b-from-right b-delay03">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

When trying to add the styles of `position: relative; right: -100%;` to the h2 element the text moves right 100%. However, if I change the styles to `position: relative; top: -100%;` the text refuses to move up 100%. I'm assuming this has someting to do with flexbox and positioning. What should I do to fix this?

```
.d-flex-center {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.d-flex {
    display: flex!important;
}
.b-wrapper .inner-wrapper {
    margin: 0 15px -17px 15px;
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell what is the functionality you are trying to achieve ? So that we can suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Top positioning is not working here, because you are using a percentage value, while the container has no height.  It would be the same for a positive value too.

To see your top/bottom positioning take effect, either

- Give the containing element a height, so the percentage value will be calculated based on that

or

- Use a pixel value for top/bottom positioning

### Using `%` value

Parent container must have specified height, so that percentage will be calculated correctly.

```css
.d-flex-center {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.d-flex {
    display: flex!important;
}
.b-wrapper .inner-wrapper {
    margin: 0 15px -17px 15px;
}
.inner-wrapper {
  height: 150px;    /* container height */
}
h2 {
  position: relative;
  right: -40%;
  top: -20%;      /* -20% is now equivalent to -30px (20% of 150px height) */
}
```

```html
<div class="b-wrapper d-flex d-flex-center">
     <div class="inner-wrapper">
         <h2 class="b-animate h b-from-top b-delay03">Project 3</h2>
         <p class="b-animate p b-from-right b-delay03">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

### Using `px` value

Pixel value will always be consistent, as it is not calculated based on another value.  (No need to specify height on parent container.)

```css
.d-flex-center {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.d-flex {
    display: flex!important;
}
.b-wrapper .inner-wrapper {
    margin: 0 15px -17px 15px;
}
h2 {
  position: relative;
  right: -40%;
  top: -30px;    /* -30px === -30px */
}
```

```html
<div class="b-wrapper d-flex d-flex-center">
     <div class="inner-wrapper">
         <h2 class="b-animate h b-from-top b-delay03">Project 3</h2>
         <p class="b-animate p b-from-right b-delay03">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
     </div>
 </div>
```